# How to limit the maximum no. of rows that a select query can return

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Need to limit the maximum no. of rows that a select query can return when its done using a particular login. So basically we would like to append a limit clause to any select query fired by a particular user.

Is this possible in PostgreSQL? If so, how can this be done?

Note:-  we need to force the limiting without the need for any intervention from the person executing the query. Which means creating of functions doesn't help in this scenario as the user has to add/append the function name in the SELECT query.
The user just has to apply SELECT * FROM TABLE NAME and the return data limited instead of returning the Whole data.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Create views that limit the data, grant only SELECT privilege on the views. Or use row level security

Comment: If you LIMIT: which records do you want toi avoid? Which do you want to keep?

Comment: This is a problem best solved in your ORM or maybe even a custom db pooling query. The unfortunate side effect is that you may very well make some queries run slower

Comment: @wildplasser: i just need to show 30% of the rows in a particular table, when the developers hits the query SELECT * OR SELECT Coulmnid FROM TABLE. Do not have a need to limit specific rows/records, the need is not to show old data to the developer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- but still if i use views, its again depending on the developer to use views or tables. Instead of view, if the developer uses the table, then again he can gain whole access to data.

Comment: If the developer has no select privilege on the table, he/she has to use the view